# Cocos2D UITextView not rotating with GLView

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, orientation, uitextview, autorotate

So I added a UITextView to my OpenGL view in Cocos2D.
Did some rotation to fit my landscape view and all. But somehow when the whole scene rotates, the textview doesn't. I've tried

```
[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window].autoresizesSubviews = YES;
```

and including these functions but it still stays put..

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
- (void) willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

any ideas?

i've added it to my openGLView using:

```
[[[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] window] addSubview:self];
```

my class inherits from UITextView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open file `GameConfig.h`, define Autorotation type. Hope it will help.

Comment: thanks for the response.
i checked and I have this in the GameConfig.h
    #define GAME_AUTOROTATION kGameAutorotationUIViewController
so i guess it's already defined? the autorotation works for the gl components, only the textview is not rotating right.

Comment: Try this line [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:self]; not use window.